# Usage of capistranodb_ignore_tables and db_ignore_data_tables option

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I use [capistrano-db-tasks](https://github.com/sgruhier/capistrano-db-tasks).

How to skip certain table while running `cap production db:pull` task?

Ideally I need a way to download a production db without one table (***versions***).

From [documentation](https://github.com/sgruhier/capistrano-db-tasks):

```
# if you want to exclude table from dump
set :db_ignore_tables, []

# if you want to exclude table data (but not table schema) from dump
set :db_ignore_data_tables, []
```

I tried it as following (in `config/deploy.rb`):

```
set :db_ignore_tables, [:versions]
set :db_ignore_data_tables, [:versions]
```

But it seem to still download the whole `versions` table with data :(.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it occurred, [`db_ignore_data_tables`](https://github.com/sgruhier/capistrano-db-tasks/blob/master/lib/capistrano-db-tasks/database.rb#L97) is not available for MySQL database, and only for PostgreSQL.

Unfortunate fact.

Also, `db_ignore_tables` option is not available from gem release version, so you should specify that you want to use github:

```
gem 'capistrano-db-tasks', require: false, github: 'sgruhier/capistrano-db-tasks'
```